# Как сравнить значения строк массива с названиями групп в - SPGroupCollection?

Tags: c#, массивы, sharepoint

Есть массив строковых значений(`artelFieldSplit`), они являют собою названия групп, которые нужно проверить. То есть сделать проверку, есть ли на сайте группы с такими именами, если есть - то просто добавить пользователя туда, если нет - создать такие группы и тоже добавить туда пользователя.(Это задача вся)

Вообще, не могу разобраться именно с проверкой. Как организовать проверку строк массива на совпадение с названиями групп? Говорю сразу, быдло код, это раз. И что последний кусок - нагугленый.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using Microsoft.Office.InfoPath;
using System.Linq;

namespace External_User_Request.UserRequestReceiver
{
/// <summary>
/// List Item Events
/// </summary>
public class UserRequestReceiver : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An item was added.
    /// </summary>
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        SPSite site = new SPSite("http://dev-mss-01/Receiver/");
        using (SPWeb spWeb = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            ///Get the needed item in the library
            spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            SPList list = spWeb.Lists["External User Request"];
            SPQuery querry = new SPQuery();
            querry.RowLimit = 1;
            querry.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending ='FALSE'/></OrderBy>";
            SPListItem maxItem = list.GetItems(querry).Cast<SPListItem>().FirstOrDefault();
            int lastItemId = -1;
            string[] artelFieldSplit;
            string[] activeFieldSplit;
            string[] taskFieldSplit;
            var userID = "";
            var accountName = "";
            if (maxItem != null)
            {
                lastItemId = maxItem.ID;
            }
            //Put the items(group DisplayName) to arrays
            foreach (SPListItem item in list.GetItems(querry))
            {
                if (lastItemId == maxItem.ID)
                {
                    string artelField =      item["Artel_x0020_Field"].ToString();
                    artelFieldSplit = artelField.Split('\n');

                    string activeField = item["Active_x0020_Field"].ToString();
                    activeFieldSplit = activeField.Split('\n');

                    string taskField = item["Task_x0020_Field"].ToString();
                    taskFieldSplit = taskField.Split('\n');

                    userID += item["User_x0020_ID"].ToString();
                    accountName += item["Full_x0020_Name"].ToString();

                }

            }
            // Тут моя проблемка и начинается:)
            string groupName = artelFieldSplit.ToArray().ToString();
            foreach(SPListItem item in groupName)
            {
                SPGroupCollection groups = spWeb.Groups;
                foreach (SPGroup group in groups)
                {
                    if (spWeb.Groups.OfType<SPGroup>().Count(g => g.Name.Equals(artelFieldSplit.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) > 0)
                    {
                        SPGroup Mygroup= spWeb.Groups[artelFieldSplit.ToString()];
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем вам массив строк? Заведите `HashSet`, и дело с концом.

Comment: Видел примеры, но как реализовать - пока не совсем представляю(

Comment: Сорри, я уехал в отпуск. Надеюсь, кто-нибудь ещё подскажет.

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь методом [`GetCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroupcollection.getcollection.aspx) класса `SPGroupCollection`. Принимает `string[]` имен групп или `int[]` идентификаторов групп и возвращает новую `SPGroupCollection`.

Чтобы проверить конкретное имя группы `name`:

```
private static bool CheckIfGroupExistsBasedOnName(SPGroupCollection collection, string name)
{
    return (collection.GetCollection(new string[] { name }).Count > 0);
}
```

А `spWeb.Groups.GetCollection(artelFieldSplit)` вернет коллекцию, каждый элемент которой - существующая группа, останется добавить пользователя в цикле.

Для реализации логики *вернуть или создать-и-вернуть* для групп можно адаптировать код из https://sacarter.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/console-app-get-create-sharepoint-site-group/ - оставлю ссылкой, поскольку это выходит за рамки заданного вопроса